# ¿Cómo podemos permitir muchos conjuntos de reglas de sintaxis para el idioma de origen y solo una sintaxis permitida en el idioma de destino?

Tags: regex

Esperaba tener un lenguaje de programación compilado que tolerara un número limitado de errores de sintaxis.

Deseamos diseñar un compilador donde el material fuente contenga muchos errores ortográficos diferentes y el idioma de destino tenga una ortografía muy estandarizada.

Por ejemplo, consideremos los matemáticos.

En las lecciones de matemáticas, los estudiantes ven cosas como **(1, 8)**, que representa un conjunto de números de mínimo **1** y máximo **8**.

¿Qué enfoque se considera la mejor práctica para escribir un programa (un "pre-compiler") que traduzca muchas sintaxis diferentes en una sola sintaxis?

¿Es posible que `,` y   y `;` se asigne todo a un token para delimitadores infijos?

En la siguiente tabla, la columna denominada "**ORIGEN**" siempre tiene el mismo valor sin importar cuál sea la entrada.

| **ORIGEN** | **RESULTADO** | OBSERVACIONES ADICIONALES |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `(0,∞)` | `(0, ∞)` | La entrada no tiene espacio después de la coma La salida tiene un espacio después de la coma. |
| `(0, ∞)` | `(0, ∞)` | La entrada es la misma que la salida |
| `(0: ∞)` | `(0, ∞)` | espacio de dos puntos |
| `(0:∞)` | `(0, ∞)` | sin espacio después de dos puntos |
| `(0; ∞)` | `(0, ∞)` | espacio después del punto y coma |
| `(0;∞)` | `(0, ∞)` | sin espacio después del punto y coma |
| `[0, ∞]` | `(0, ∞)` | espacio después de la coma |
| `[0,∞]` | `(0, ∞)` | sin espacio después de la coma |
| `[0: ∞]` | `(0, ∞)` | espacio después de dos puntos |
| `[0:∞]` | `(0, ∞)` | sin espacio después de dos puntos |
| `[0; ∞]` | `(0, ∞)` | espacio después del punto y coma |
| `[0;∞]` | `(0, ∞)` | sin espacio después del punto y coma |
| `{0, ∞}` | `(0, ∞)` | espacio después de la coma |
| `{0,∞}` | `(0, ∞)` | sin espacio después de la coma |
| `{0: ∞}` | `(0, ∞)` | espacio después de dos puntos |
| `{0:∞}` | `(0, ∞)` | sin espacio después de dos puntos |
| `{0; ∞}` | `(0, ∞)` | espacio después del punto y coma |
| `{0;∞}` | `(0, ∞)` | sin espacio después del punto y coma |

---

Una aplicación del mundo real podría ser un compilador que lee algo más fácil de usar y legible que expresiones regulares o ***regex***.

El compilador genera expresiones regulares.

| Idioma de origen | Idioma de destino | Español |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `(0, ∞) de "x+y"` | `(?:x\+y)*` | cero o más de `x+y` |
| `(1, ∞) de "*"` | `\*+` | uno o más asteriscos `*` |
| `(1,∞) de "+"` | `\++` | uno o más de `+` |

Relativamente hablando, `(0, ∞) de "x+y"` es más fácil de leer y comprender para los estudiantes que `(?:x\+y)*`.

Las expresiones regulares pueden resultar difíciles de leer y escribir para los seres humanos.

Me gustaría trabajar en un compilador que sea tolerante a fallas para una colección muy pequeña de errores de sintaxis.

Comment: Buenas, Samuel, bienvenido al sitio, ¿le has echado un ojo a [tour] y [ask]? No me queda claro qué preguntas exactamente. En cualquier caso hacer un pre-compilador para que expresiones que te has inventado se convirtan en regex está bastante fuera del alcance de este sitio